# Creating tree from list of input and then increment a counter anytime there is a child and retrieve the id of the parent node?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have an input text file like this:

```
Bunny -vs- Dog
Bunny Corners -vs- Dog Corners
Bunny Penalty -vs- Dog Penalty
Duck -vs- Cat
Tiger -vs- Lion
Tiger Corners -vs Lion Corners
```

I need to produce an output text file that assign (original id-match id) for these matches so the expected output will be:

```
1: Bunny -vs- Dog
1-1: Bunny Corners -vs- Dog Corners
1-2: Bunny Penalty -vs- Dog Penalty
2: Duck -vs- Cat
3: Tiger -vs- Lion
3-1: Tiger Corners -vs Lion Corners
```

Since Bunny vs Dog play with each other three time that's why they got 1-1 or 1-2 under this format ("the original match id- number of times they have met until now"). I originally thought of having a Dictionary<int,string> but finding duplication in dictionary seems like a weird thing to do.

How should I implement a tree where each parent root is the original match with a correspond id and then add in child that are matches with the substring Corners or Penalty and they will have the same match id just like the parents but any more occurrences of the child will increase a counter?

```
Ex: 
"Bunny -vs- Dog" => parent node
"Bunny Corners -vs- Dog Corners => child of "Bunny -vs- Dog"
"Bunny Penalty -vs- Dog Penalty => another child of "Bunny -vs- Dog"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This version of the answer accounts for both points brought up in the comments.*

Keep in mind that if you change the format of the text you may need to adjust the `Regex` to get `secondWord`. [Here is a link to the current regex.](https://regex101.com/r/AKCHBh/1)

**Main Code:**

```
//Path of the file you want to reading
const string readPath = @"C:\Users\ak\Desktop\testInput.txt";
//Path of the file you want to save to
const string writePath = @"C:\Users\ak\Desktop\testOutput.txt";

//Get the content of readPath
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(readPath);

//Create new List for firstWords
List<string> firstWords = new List<string>();
//Create new List for secondWords
List<string> secondWords = new List<string>();
//Create New List for Parents
List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>();


//Go through each line of your file
int firstDigit = 1;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    //Get the first word of the line
    string firstWord = line.Split(' ')[0];
    //Get the second word of the line
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"-vs-\s(\S+)"); 
    string secondWord = regex.Match(line).Groups[1].Value;

    //Add new Parent for the words if it doesn't exist already
    if (!parents.Where(o => o._firstWord == firstWord).Select(o => o._secondWord).Contains(secondWord))
    {
        parents.Add(new Parent(firstWord, secondWord, firstDigit));
        firstDigit++;
    }

    //Add firstWord to List
    firstWords.Add(firstWord);
    //Add secondWord to List
    secondWords.Add(secondWord);
}

//Go through each firstWord
int index = 0;
foreach (string word in firstWords)
{
    //Get the Parent corresponding to the word
    Parent parent = parents.Where(o => o._firstWord == word && o._secondWord == secondWords[index]).FirstOrDefault();

    //Add the numbers to the text lines
    if (parent._firstAppearance)
    {
        //Only one digit => ex: 1
        lines[index] = parent._firstDigit + ": " + lines[index];
        parent._firstAppearance = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Two digits => ex: 1-2
        lines[index] = parent._firstDigit + "-" + parent._secondDigit + ": " + lines[index];
        parent._secondDigit++;
    }

    index++;
}

//Save text to new file
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writePath, true))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

**Parent Class:**

```
class Parent
{
    public string _firstWord { get; }
    public string _secondWord { get; }
    public int _firstDigit { get; }
    public int _secondDigit { get; set; }
    public bool _firstAppearance { get; set; }

    public Parent(string firstWord, string secondWord, int firstDigit)
    {
        _firstWord = firstWord;
        _secondWord = secondWord;
        _firstDigit = firstDigit;
        _secondDigit = 1;
        _firstAppearance = true;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add these **namespaces**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: If you change the sequence then your answer will fail. ex. Move ```Bunny Penalty -vs- Dog Penalty``` to last line

Comment: Now it won't :)

Comment: Thank you @Ottxr, would your code work if one day I add in maybe Bunny -v- Duck? since I recognize you just take into account  the first word?

Comment: @CatyCatCat Now it would :)